# Java ResultSet adding zeros

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc, resultset

Weird behavior here.

On the SQL Server database the columns type are Numeric(20,6) but the resultset retrieves the values added by a bunch of zeros:

Table: 952.346,44 - 890.00

Resultset: 952346.440000 -> 890000.000000

The application is running on WAS 8.5, Java 7 with JDBC Driver sqljdbc4-4.1.jar

Comment: Technically there is no difference between 952346.44 and 952346.440000. If you need formatting you could format those numbers separately.

Comment: This is unclear.  What is `890.00`?  Based on the preceding example it looks like you're using a continental European locale where the dot is the thousands separator and the comma is the decimal separator.  `890.00` is invalid syntax in that system.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned `Numeric(20,6)` which means the scale of the number is 6

And thats the reason the same precision is considered in Java.

Now if you want to reduce it 2 decimal places, you can simply update column type or if it is already in production you can simply reduce the number in JAVA with various possible ways, on of which is as follows:

```
Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f", 952346.440000));
```

Comment: Better would be to use `BigDecimal.setScale`

Answer (score 0):

Your column is a `NUMERIC(20,6)`, the 6 there is the scale, and that specifies the number of decimals. In other words, the values already **were** `952346.440000` and `890000.000000`, and JDBC just returned them according to specification.

If you need only 2 decimals, then use `NUMERIC(20,2)`. Or rescale the number in your code using one of the `BigDecimal.setScale` methods.